# How to calculate syllables in text with regex and Java

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I have text as a `String` and need to calculate number of syllables in each word. I've tried to split all text into array of words and than processed each word separately. I used regular expressions for that. But pattern for syllables doesn't work as it should. Please advice how to change it to calculate correct number of syllables. My initial code.

```
public int getNumSyllables()
{
    String[] words = getText().toLowerCase().split("[a-zA-Z]+");
    int count=0;
    List <String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String word: words){
            tokens = Arrays.asList(word.split("[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*[aeiou]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]*"));
            count+= tokens.size();

            }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Determining the syllables is much, much harder than you think. Try applying the OP's rule to "reinvented" or "nuance". And you have ignored 'y' so your rule will not work for even simple words like "really". But 'y' is not always a vowel. And sometimes (rarely) 'w' is a vowel, as in "cwm"

Comment: instead of [bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz] you can simply write [^aeiou]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question is from a Java Course of UCSD, am I right?

**I think you should provide enough information for this question,** so that it won't confused people who want to offer some help. And here I have my own solution, which already been tested by the test case from the local program, also the OJ from UCSD.

You missed some important information about the definition of syllable in this question. **Actually I think the key point of this problem is how should you deal with the `e`.** For example, let's say there is a combination of                     `te`. And if you put `te` in the middle of a word, of course it should be counted as a syllable; However if it's at the end of a word, the `e` should be thought as a `silent e` in English, so it should not be thought as a syllable.

That's it. And I would like to write down my thought with some pseudo code:

```
  if(last character is e) {
        if(it is silent e at the end of this word) {
           remove the  silent e;
           count the rest part as regular;
        } else {
           count++;
  } else {
        count it as regular;
  }
}
```

You may find that **I am not only using regex** to deal with this problem. Actually I have thought about it: can this question really be done only using regex? My answer is: nope, I don't think so. At least now, with the knowledge UCSD gives us, it's too difficult to do that. Regex is a powerful tool, it can map the desired characters very fast. However regex is missing some functionality. Take the `te` as example again, regex won't be able to think twice when it is facing the word like `teate` (I made up this word just for example). If our regex pattern would count the first `te` as syllable, then why the last `te` not?

Meanwhile, UCSD actually have talked about it on the assignment paper:

> If you find yourself doing mental gymnastics to come up with a single regex to count syllables directly, that's usually an indication that there's a simpler solution (hint: consider a loop over characters--see the next hint below). Just because a piece of code (e.g. a regex) is shorter does not mean it is always better.

The hint here is that, you should think this problem together with some loop, combining with regex.

OK, I should finally show my code now:

```
protected int countSyllables(String word)
{
    // TODO: Implement this method so that you can call it from the 
    // getNumSyllables method in BasicDocument (module 1) and 
    // EfficientDocument (module 2).
    int count = 0;
    word = word.toLowerCase();

    if (word.charAt(word.length()-1) == 'e') {
        if (silente(word)){
            String newword = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);
            count = count + countit(newword);
        } else {
            count++;
        }
    } else {
        count = count + countit(word);
    }
    return count;
}

private int countit(String word) {
    int count = 0;
    Pattern splitter = Pattern.compile("[^aeiouy]*[aeiouy]+");
    Matcher m = splitter.matcher(word);

    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

private boolean silente(String word) {
    word = word.substring(0, word.length()-1);

    Pattern yup = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]");
    Matcher m = yup.matcher(word);

    if (m.find()) {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}
```

You may find that besides from the given method `countSyllables`, I also create two additional methods `countit` and `silente`. `countit` is for counting the syllables inside the word, `silente` is trying to figure it out that is this word end with a silent `e`. And it should also be noticed that the definition of `not silent e`. For example, `the` should be consider `not silent e`, while `ate` is considered `silent e`.

And here is the status my code has already passed the test, from both local test case and OJ from UCSD:

[image: from local test case]

And from OJ the test result:

[image: from Coursera OJ]

P.S: It should be fine to use something like [^aeiouy] directly, because the word is parsed before we call this method. Also change to lowercase is necessary, that would save a lot of work dealing with the uppercase. What we want is only the number of syllables.
Talking about number, an elegant way is to define `count` as static, so the private method could directly use `count++` inside. But now it's fine.

Feel free to contact me if you still don't get the method of this question :)

Comment: Thank you Anthony, for the explanation detailed

Comment: I don't recommend using count as static, as this makes it no longer thread safe.  If two threads are trying to count different files, the count will be shared by both, and cause data corruption.  Instead, just make it an instance variable at the class level, or avoid the global variables completely, for anything that is changing to ensure scalability.  Just my 2cents worth

Comment: @Armand thanks for the review, and I think your point make perfect sense. I was a Java beginner when I post this answer two years ago. I would take a look at the code and try to make it nicer if I have time.

Answer (score 3):

Using the concept of user5500105, I have developed the following method to calculate the number of Syllables in a word. The rules are:

- consecutive vowels are counted as 1 syllable. eg. "ae" "ou" are 1 syllable
- Y is considered as a vowel
- e at the end is counted as syllable if e is the only vowel: eg: "the" is one syllable, since "e" at the end is the only vowel while "there" is also 1 syllable because "e" is at the end and there is another vowel in the word.

  ```
   public int countSyllables(String word) {
       ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
       String regexp = "[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*[aeiouy]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*";
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
       Matcher m = p.matcher(word.toLowerCase());


       while (m.find()) {
           tokens.add(m.group());
       }

   //check if e is at last and e is not the only vowel or not
       if( tokens.size() > 1 && tokens.get(tokens.size()-1).equals("e")  )
           return tokens.size()-1; // e is at last and not the only vowel so total syllable -1 
       return tokens.size(); 
   }
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This gives you a number of <strike>syllables</strike> vowels in a word:

```
public int getNumVowels(String word) {

    String regexp = "[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*[aeiouy]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(word.toLowerCase());

    int count = 0;

    while (m.find()) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You can call it on every word in your string array:

```
    String[] words = getText().split("\\s+");
    for (String word : words ) {
      System.out.println("Word: " + word + ", vowels: " + getNumVowels(word));
    }
```

**Update:** as freerunner noted, calculating the number of syllables is more complicated than just counting vowels. One need to take into account combinations like *ou*, *ui*, *oo*, the final silent *e* and possibly something else. As I am not a native English speaker, I am not sure what the correct algorithm would be.

Comment: It's a good solution but "y" is also considered as a syllable. So the regex should be:                                                                                           String regexp = "[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*[aeiouy]+[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxz]*";

Comment: Futhermore, there is one more condition for a syllable, i.e. If the letter 'e' is at the end of a word (e.g there) and there are other vowels in the word, its not counted as a syllable. The above code does not satisfy the condition.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it.  This is about as simple an algorithm I could come up with.

```
   public static int syllables(String s) {
      final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([ayeiou]+)");
      final String lowerCase = s.toLowerCase();
      final Matcher m = p.matcher(lowerCase);
      int count = 0;
      while (m.find())
         count++;

      if (lowerCase.endsWith("e"))
         count--;

      return count < 0 ? 1 : count;
   }
```

I use this in combination with a soundex function to determine if words sound alike.  The syllable count improves accuracy of my soundex function.

Note: This is strictly for counting the syllables in a word.  I assume you can parse your input for words using something like `java.util.StringTokenizer`.

Answer (score 0):

Your line

```
String[] words = getText().toLowerCase().split("[a-zA-Z]+");
```

is splitting ON words, and returning only the space between words! You want to split on the space between words, as follows:

```
String[] words = getText().toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: this works if the only delimiter is white space.  If you want to ignore all non-word characters, like Parenthesis, quotes, etc.., I would recommend String[] words = getText().toLowerCase().split("(\\W|_)+")   this way, Fitness-Center becomes "Fitness" and "Center" and helps to ensure accuracy in parsing syllables across hyphenated words. It also removes all punctuation.  It does not consider number as invalid, so numbers will be returned so they can be handled according to parser's requirements

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as the following :

```
public int getNumSyllables()
{
    return getSyllables(getTokens("[a-zA-Z]+"));
}

protected List<String> getWordTokens(String word,String pattern)
{
    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher(word);

    while (m.find()) {
        tokens.add(m.group());
    }

    return tokens;
}

private int getSyllables(List<String> tokens)
{
    int count=0;

    for(String word : tokens)
    if(word.toLowerCase().endsWith("e") && getWordTokens(word.toLowerCase().substring(0, word.length()-1), "[aeiouy]+").size() > 0)
        count+=getWordTokens(word.toLowerCase().substring(0, word.length()-1), "[aeiouy]+").size();
    else
        count+=getWordTokens(word.toLowerCase(), "[aeiouy]+").size();

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I count the `the` separately, then split the text based on words which are ended with e.
Then counting the syllables, here is my implementation:

```
int syllables = 0;
    word = word.toLowerCase();
    if(word.contains("the ")){
        syllables ++;
    }
    String[] split = word.split("e!$|e[?]$|e,|e |e[),]|e$");

    ArrayList<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern tokSplitter = Pattern.compile("[aeiouy]+");

    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        String s = split[i];
        Matcher m = tokSplitter.matcher(s);

        while (m.find()) {
            tokens.add(m.group());
        }
    }

    syllables += tokens.size();
```

I've testesd an all test cases are passed.

Answer (score -1):

You are using method split incorrectly. This method recieve separator. Need write something like this:

```
String[] words = getText().toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

But if you want to count the number of syllables, it is enough to count the number of vowels:

```
String input = "text";
Set<Character> vowel = new HashSet<>();
vowel.add('a');
vowel.add('e');
vowel.add('i');
vowel.add('o');
vowel.add('u');

int count = 0;
for (char c : input.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
    if (vowel.contains(c)){
        count++;
    }
}

System.out.println("count = " + count);
```

Comment: Did you take into consideration that your method does not count syllable of words like "Sea" correctly because you're just counting the vowels! Sea has one syllable but your method should return 2.

Comment: Yes you are right. I thought, that for English, as well as for Russian count of syllables equals count of vowels. I was wrong. But other regex also wrong, because they return wrong answer for words like 'account'. Regarding that, I think usage of regex for this task is bad idea

Comment: RegExp, I think, is more efficient that this example, as this example relies on a hashset of char[1], which translates the char to a hashcode, then stores the hashcode in the hashtable.  the contains() method then has to find all registered entries with said hashcode, then for each hashcode, it then does an equality check for the key to determine if it is the correct match, and then it returns the Boolean true/false.  I struggle to determine if this is any faster or more efficient than RegExp solution.  It certainly isn't any more accurate.  But, this is a good start at trying to solve it.